# Indenting code in JTextArea

Tags: java, editor, indentation, jtextarea

I am developing a kind of **java editor** for myself in the java language. I am having problem in making it indent the code. I am using JTextArea to type the code, and I want it to increase the indent after every **{** bracket and decrease the indent after every **}** bracket. Please help me.

Comment: Consider the following  source as an option for research, perhaps indentation won't be the only struggle in building a good text editor. http://texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?JavaBasedEditors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to implement a `DocumentFilter` to handle special processing when a specific character is entered.

Here is a example that handles the newline character. When the newline character is found "white space" will be added to the Document so that the left edge of the text matches the previous line:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NewLineFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if ("\n".equals(str))
            str = addWhiteSpace(fb.getDocument(), offs);

        super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if ("\n".equals(str))
            str = addWhiteSpace(fb.getDocument(), offs);

        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    }

    private String addWhiteSpace(Document doc, int offset)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        StringBuilder whiteSpace = new StringBuilder("\n");
        Element root = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
        int line = root.getElementIndex( offset );
        int length = doc.getLength();

        for (int i = root.getElement(line).getStartOffset(); i < length; i++)
        {
            String temp = doc.getText(i, 1);

            if (temp.equals(" ") || temp.equals("\t"))
            {
                whiteSpace.append(temp);
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        return whiteSpace.toString();
    }
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 50);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new NewLineFilter() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NewLineFilter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(textArea) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your case the code would be similar. When you find a "{" you would want to insert a "\n", then add the whitespace and then add additional characters for the indentation.

> I want it to increase the indent after every { bracket and decrease the indent after every } bracket.

Also, instead of handling "{" "}" separately, another approach is to just handle the "{". Then you would add an empty line and also add the "}" at the same time. This way you make sure that you always have matching pairs of brackets.